Jenkins renaming the file from workspace folder
My Jenkins pipeline(freestyle) creates an HTML report in one of the folders(RUNREPORTS) in the workspace and the HTML file name will have the name Reporting<date&time).html.
Scenario:
The folder in the workspace is RUNREPORTS and the file inside this "Reporting202411051234.html
I need to rename this file as TestFile.html and move it to a new folder "TOSHARE" within the same workspace.
Finally, delete the *.html file from the RUNREPORTS folder.

If your Jenkins machine is on linux, you can use:
mv Reporting*.html TOSHARE/TestFile.html

If Windows:
Rename-Item -Path "Reporting*.html" -NewName "TOSHARE\TestFile.html"

You can add the above command by adding an "Execute shell" build step.

It sounds like you want to rename these files and then explicitly delete these reports which implies you are not deleting the whole of the workspace between builds. By also having this TOSHARE folder inside the workspace you are implying there that you are not using the archive artifacts or publish HTML plugins to handle these reports and store them outside the workspace.
I would look into using the publishHtml plugin this would avoid the need to rename and move them and keep the workspace. It is also best practice to delete the workspace so that each build is fresh.
